# Calculate moment of inertia of rigid body

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a somewhat complicated shape that I need to know the moment of inertia of and don't want to calculate manually. I can pretty easily model the shape and material in blender, then tell it to use the mesh as the shape, but I can't seem to figure out how to get blender to simply spit out the calculated moment of inertia. Can blender do that, or do I need to use different software?

Thanks.